# Left join is not working fine

Tags: mysql, sql

table tbl_students

```
Student_pid     name                email
1               waheed               waheed@gmail.com
2               fareed               fareed@gmail.com
```

table r_job_invitations

```
id_job   email
101       waheed@gmail.com
101       fareed@gmail.com
123       waheed@gmail.com
123       fareed@gmail.com
```

table r_job_groups

```
student_id   job_id   group_id
1             101       1
2             101       2
1             123       1
2             123       2
```

From the above 3 tables i am trying get the students with a condition. This my query:

```
    $studentQuery = $conn->query("SELECT
      s.student_pid,jbi.test_status
       FROM `r_job_groups` jtg 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_students s ON jtg.student_id=s.student_pid 
        LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON jbi.email=s.student_email 
         where jtg.group_id=".$group." and job_id=".$jobID );
```

From above query, for values of

```
$group = 1 and $jobID = 101
```

Result is coming like this:

```
student_pid
1
1
2
2
```

Actual result should be like this:

```
student_pid
    1
    2
```

> my issue is i am getting students doble time

As per query, that result should give 2 students but it is resulting 4 students because of job id is not working fine joins.
how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be careful with the use of vars  in your select  you could be subsject  to a sql injection

anyway  you could use distinct for avoid duplicated  value

```
  $studentQuery = $conn->query("SELECT DISCINCT
  s.student_pid
   FROM `r_job_groups` jtg 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_students s ON jtg.student_id=s.student_pid 
    LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON jbi.email=s.student_email 
     where jtg.group_id=".$group." and jtg job_id=".$jobID );
```

or  use  a distinct dinamic table

```
  $studentQuery = $conn->query("SELECT 
  s.student_pid
   FROM `r_job_groups` jtg 
    LEFT JOIN ( select distinct student_pid 
           from tbl_students )  s ON jtg.student_id=s.student_pid 
    LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON jbi.email=s.student_email 
     where jtg.group_id=".$group." and jtg.job_id=".$jobID );
```

And lloking to your data sample  try also to change the order of the joi  table

```
$studentQuery = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT s.student_pid
      FROM  tbl_students s  
      LEFT `r_job_groups` jtg  s ON jtg.student_id=s.student_pid 
      LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON jbi.email=s.student_email 
     where jtg.group_id=".$group." and job_id=".$jobID );
```

Comment: @AbdulWaheed   please which is the table nme for  job_id  ? ... any way the distincnt is applied  at the result not at the where condition ..

Comment: Is not clear to my why  you don't use distinct  .. based  on your result you should use  this clause because (i repeat myself) the clause is applied on result and not involve the row filter (where clause)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed  . i have update the answer .. let me know

Comment: Can you see the question i have updated i need another feild as well due to that it is messing for me i guess.`s.student_pid,jbi.test_status`

Answer (score 1):

The invitations table seems totally unnecessary -- and the cause of your duplicates.  Write the query as:

```
SELECT s.student_pid
FROM `r_job_groups` jtg LEFT JOIN
      tbl_students s
      ON jtg.student_id = s.student_pid 
WHERE jtg.group_id = ".$group." and jtg.job_id = ".$jobID;
```

I also suspect that you want `JOIN` and not `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Invitation table is needed for me check the updated question once. @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT jbi.*, s.student_pid,jbi.test_status FROM 
`r_job_groups` jtg LEFT JOIN tbl_students s ON jtg.student_id=s.student_pid
 LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON jbi.email=s.student_email
 where jtg.group_id=1 and jtg.job_id=109 and jtg.job_id=jbi.id_job
```